# 'if' statement for when two random numbers are equal

Tags: python, random, probability, montecarlo

I am trying to have a situation in which when we toss two coins at the same, if we get heads on both coins we win and if we get tails on both coins we lose.

I have been able to generate the results of tossing one of the coins separately using:

```
def coin_one():
one = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(100)]
for x in one:
    if x <= 50:
        print('Heads')
    else:
        print('Tails')
```

and also for the second coin using basically the same method:

```
def coin_two():
two = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(100)]
for x in two:
  if x <= 50:
    print('Heads')
  else:
    print('Tails')
```

I am trying to add a condition that will print('win') if we have 'heads' in both coin_one and coin_two when the two coins are tossed at the same time. How do I do this?

Comment: `print('win') if random.randint(0,1) == random.randint(0,1) else print('lose')`

Comment: Start with a function that tosses two coins at the same time. At the moment you have two different functions, which both toss 100 coins separately and prints the results.

Comment: It might help you think about it to create a single function that tosses a single coin and returns "heads" or "tails". Then other functions you write can use that function instead of having to do less readable things with `random.randint()`

Comment: 'I am trying to have a situation in which when we toss two coins at the same, if we get heads on both coins we win and if we get tails on both coins we lose.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine both computations under one method, and do the checks in one pass? Since you're randomizing a coin flip; a binary value of 0/1 is enough to represent this probability accurately (*with the added bonus of using their implicit `bool` values to do the equality checks*).

```
def coin_toss():
    first_coin_tosses = [random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(100)]
    second_coin_tosses = [random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(100)]

    for first_coin_toss, second_coin_toss in zip(first_coin_tosses, second_coin_tosses):
        if first_coin_toss and second_coin_toss:  # Both 1's
            # We win.
        elif not first_coin_toss and not second_coin_toss:  # Both 0's
            # We lose.
        else:
            # if we get a 1 on one coin and and 0 on the other 
            # or vice versa then we neither win nor lose (we try again).
```

Comment: We have three outcomes for the experiment: if we get heads on both coins we win (both 1's), if we get tails on both coins we lose (both 0's) and finally if we get a 1 on one coin and and 0 on the other or vice versa then we neither win nor lose (we try again)

Comment: Update to make it more clear which control flow branch belongs to what outcome. @TupilweSinyangwe

Answer (score 0):

Write two functions that will return random value from 1-100.
Then write below condition like
If firstnum >50 and secondnun>50:
      Print head
Else:
     Print tail

Comment: Really? First, there is no need of writing two functions. Second, you should write your answer using formatted code-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result in one of the following two ways. 
First method:
This is straight forward solution.
Store all the coin one and coin two results in a list and return it to the calling method and check for the equality.

Second method:
You can return (actually yielding) back for each coin 1 and 2 value and check it in the calling method.

```
import random

def coin_one():
    one = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(100)]
    for x in one:
       if x <= 50:
           print('Heads')
           #Use yield to return value and also continue method execution
           yield 'Heads' #Add this line
       else:
           print('Tails')
           yield 'Tails' #Add this line


def coin_two():
    two = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(100)]
    for x in two:
       if x <= 50:
           print('Heads')
           yield 'Heads'
       else:
           print('Tails')
           yield 'Tails'

coin_1_result = coin_one()
coin_2_result = coin_two()
for coin_1, coin_2 in zip(coin_1_result, coin_2_result):
    if coin_1 == 'Heads' and coin_2 == 'Heads':
        print('win')
    else:
        print('loss')
```

== operator is used to check for equality of two primitive values(int, string)

yield helps in building a list by sending each result to the calling function without returning or exiting the called method (coin_one() or coin_two()).

Here zip(a, b) allows two iterables (Example: list) to be iterate at the same time. i.e. It will return coin_1_result[0], coin_2_result[0] in first iteration and in second iteration it returns coin_1_result[1], coin_2_result[1] and so on.

Additionally, you can also notice that result of win or loss will be instantly printed after yielding first set of values from both functions.

Sample output:
Heads
Tails
loss
Heads
Heads
win